# phpmyadmin 404 error on fresh ubuntu 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I regularly set up Virtualbox ubuntu setups to run as local webservers. I have set these up several times and never had an issue. However, something has changed:

1)VB guest additions no longer allow me to copy and paste (I'll worry about that later)

2)More importantly phpmyadmin no longer works as installed - Initially going to localhost/phpmyadmin gave a message that the page could not be found. So I have followed some instructions which told me to do the following in `var/www`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
```

which has created a phpmyadmin directory in `/var/www` but now I get an error saying:

> the mysqli extension is missing.

If I run phpinfo mysql and mysqli are listed.

All I have done so far is

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I found a post of a similar question which suggested I should do

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

(I've done this) and edit php.ini and uncomment the line:

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

This is not there, so I tried adding it but no joy. I have restarted apache and still no phpmyadmin.

I'm running a windows 7 machine and the guest os is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer to this.

**Dont do this step (not needed):**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
```

**Dont do this step (not needed):**

```
edit php.ini and uncomment the line:

extension=mysqli.so
```

**Do do this:**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Apparently this serves to "symlink the phpMyAdmin conf file within the apache2/conf.d/"
courtesy of pete fisher:
http://blog.peterfisher.me.uk/2012/06/27/solution-to-phpmyadmin-throwing-a-404-error/

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 13.04 I moved the phpmyadmin conf file to the enabled conf files of apache to get it working.

**Do this:**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Restart apache to get everything working.

**Do:**

`sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Happy coding