# Not able to open phpmyadmin

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [phpmyadmin 404 error on fresh ubuntu 12.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198251/phpmyadmin-404-error-on-fresh-ubuntu-12-04-install)

I installed phpmyadmin,

root@prakash-RV411-RV511-E3511-S3511-RV711:~# sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin                  install

but when I start apache 2 and enter localhost/phpmyadmin in the url I get a 404 error.

Comment: did you try http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php ?

Comment: yeah, but the same 404 error persists

Comment: Check this out http://askubuntu.com/a/198560/11932

Answer (score 1):

you probably forgot to configure phpmyadmin.

Run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Also you have to follow these steps too

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add followong line somewhre

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I reconfigured phpmyadmin, but no change in the outcome

Comment: This worked for me in 2021 (Linux mint 20.02)