# PHPMyAdmin gives 404 error in LAMP

Tags: server, lamp, phpmyadmin

I installed Lamp server in UBUNTU 16.04 with the command: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`.

The installation completed successfully. After that when I opened **localhost** in browser it displayed the "**Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page**".

BUT

When I am trying to open **localhost/phpmyadmin** I'm getting 404 error.

I'm not able to understand what is wrong here. Can anyone suggest a solution?

**Note**: Although this question may seem similar to the one here "[phpmyadmin 404 error on fresh ubuntu 12.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198251/phpmyadmin-404-error-on-fresh-ubuntu-12-04-install)", but the process I used to install LAMP is different than the one mentioned in that question. None of the solutions given there work either. Solutions suggest smylink for conf files, but when I try that it says the file or folder doesn't exist. I'm not very technical person, but I'm guessing my LAMP setup may be different from the one mentioned there.

Comment: No. The process described in "https://askubuntu.com/questions/198251/phpmyadmin-404-error-on-fresh-ubuntu-12-04-install" is different and none of the solutions given there are also not working for me.

Comment: You didn't install phpmyadmin. Did you?

Comment: Doesn't that get installed with Lamp-Server? Do I have to install it separately?

Comment: Who told you that it will get installed with that command?

Comment: I found that from one of the forums and I'm assuming since LAMP is a whole package, it must also include phpmyadmin. Does it not?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tested it in 16.04

Comment: Okay. Will try the command in your answer.

Comment: Lamp = Linux Apache Mysql PHP. Nowhere does that include phpadmin ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you used to install lamp-server won't cause phpmyadmin to be installed. You need to install it separately.

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

is the command you need now.

If you still get the error you can use this question [phpmyadmin 404 error on fresh ubuntu 12.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198251/phpmyadmin-404-error-on-fresh-ubuntu-12-04-install)

Comment: I ran the above command and installed PHPMyAdmin but I'm still getting 404 error.

Comment: @TESTasy Next use question linked with phpmyadmin getting 404 error

Comment: It took some reboots, failed login sessions and some re-installations of ubuntu-desktop, but your comments and this answer here really worked out! Thanks.